# Blockchain API v1 exception "not found"

Tags: php, bitcoin, blockchain

I've installed local service as described here https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3 and it started sucessfully. But when I'am trying to get balance of my wallet:

```
$Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain();
$Blockchain->setServiceUrl("http://localhost:3000");
$Blockchain->Wallet->credentials('myid', 'mypass');
$stats = $Blockchain->Stats->get();
var_dump($stats);
$balance = $Blockchain->Wallet->getBalance();
var_dump($balance);
```

I got following exception message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Blockchain\Exception\ApiError' with message 'No
t found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Blockchain\Blockchain.php:114
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Blockchain\Wallet\Wallet.php(47): Blockchain\Blockchain-
>post('merchant/16d72a...', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Blockchain\Wallet\Wallet.php(55): Blockchain\Wallet\Wall
et->call('balance')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wallet.php(26): Blockchain\Wallet\Wallet->getBalance()
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Blockchain\Blockchain.php on line 114
```

What causing this issue and how to resolve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused where are you coming up with those functions? `setServiceURL()` `credentials()` `getBalance()`

Are you using a custom library or wrapper?

The wallet service works off of GET requests sent to the service on localhost at the port that you told it to run on.

Here's an example:

```
$url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/merchant/YOUR-GUID/address_balance?address=1someBitcoinAddy&password=YOUR-PASSWORD&api_code=YOUR-API-CODE";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$ccc = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($ccc, true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json);
echo "</pre>";
```

A list of the available GET commands are available on their API documentation page: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'am using blockchain's library https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php . Looks pretty good, because all necessary methods are already written. However, it's now working correctly as you can see from my question.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that before. Perhaps contact blockchain support, you're likely missing an extension that their library requires. You could always just go without the library too, since there are only about a dozen of possible calls you can make.

Comment: Yeah, I've contacted them, but looks like they github community to so active.

Comment: @AlexPetrov : I face same problem can you please tell me the solution for the the same..?

Answer (score -1):

**Fetching the wallet balance**

```
$guid="GUID_HERE";
$main_password="PASSWORD_HERE";
$json_url = "http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/list?password=$main_password";
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);
$balance = $json_feed->balance;


Response:
{
  "balance": 1000
}
```

**Fetching Balance From Listing Addresses**

```
$guid="GUID_HERE";
$main_password="PASSWORD_HERE";
$json_url = "http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/list?password=$main_password";
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);

Response:
{
  "addresses": [
    {
      "balance": 1400938800,
      "address": "1Q1AtvCyKhtveGm3187mgNRh5YcukUWjQC",
      "label": "SMS Deposits",
      "total_received": 5954572400
    },
    {
      "balance": 79434360,
      "address": "1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq",
      "label": "My Wallet",
      "total_received": 453300048335
    },
    {
      "balance": 0,
      "address": "17p49XUC2fw4Fn53WjZqYAm4APKqhNPEkY",
      "total_received": 0
    }
  ]
}
```